# Is google's "autocorrect" feature available for people to use?

Tags: javascript, google-search, autocorrect

Is google's context aware auto correct (when you search, the "do you mean", and the "showing results for") available for public use? It seems to be very useful when you want to auto spellcheck.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt that it would be. Certainly if they haven’t published an API, then you shouldn’t expect it.

Google have, in the past, gone after organisations who try to use Google results without involving Google. My guess is that what you’re asking involves a preliminary search of some sort.

Also, don’t forget that even if Google supplied an API, they are just as likely to pull it or change it at their whim. They’re like that.

Comment: What? A down vote? Does the down voter have an alternative answer?